# Generate XML from Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

How would I generate the following XML code by using Java and the Soap package?

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" 
xmlns:com="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Common" 
xmlns:xm="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <ns:RetrieveString>
        <ns:model>
           <ns:keys query=Hello World;" ></ns:keys>
           <ns:instance></ns:instance>
         </ns:model>
     </ns:RetrieveString>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've gone through some tutorials, but am still confused on how to create the above XML file to call a SOAP message. For example, here is some java code:

```
SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
```

This creates this basic XML file:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   ...
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the [wsimport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) tool and use JAXB to generate the XML content.

Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxws001.htm#BNAYN

Please note that there is also a [Maven plugin for wsimport](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/).